# How to create a LINQ request

Tags: c#, linq

I can't create a LINQ request.
I have a base request:

```
        var result = from i in _dbContext.Users
                     where i.ID != CurrentUserID &&
                     //i.UserType.UserTypeID == (from a in _dbContext.UserTypes where a.UsersSelectMeetingCriteria.Any(p => p.ID == CurrentUserID) select a.UserTypeID).FirstOrDefault() &&
                     i.Services.Any(p => p.UsersSelectMeetingCriteria.Any(k => k.ID == CurrentUserID)) &&
                     i.GeographicalAreas.Any(p=>p.UsersSelectMeetingCriteria.Any(o=>o.ID == CurrentUserID)) &&
                     i.MultiplyItems.Any(r => (r.UsersSelectMeetingCriteria.Any(q => q.ID == CurrentUserID) && r.ItemType == MultiplyItemKeys.USER_TYPE)) &&
                     i.MultiplyItems.Any(s => (s.UsersSelectMeetingCriteria.Any(q => q.ID == CurrentUserID) && s.ItemType == MultiplyItemKeys.COMPANY_INVOLVED)
                     )

                     select new DataTable.UserModel()
                     { ... };
```

But I need 4 level search. If all 4 where is ok then this is first level of users, if only 3 (but 4th is NOT) - level #2, if 2 - yes, 2 - no then level #3, if only one match - level #4. How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by *level*? What is the intention of commented code? What exact filtering do you want to achieve?

Comment: This question could use a better-explained example, we don't know what the relationship of the various entities is to one another. Also good would be some example input and desired output, including why the one leads to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, and a rather wild stab in the dark, but maybe this will point you in the right direction:

```
var result = from i in _dbContext.Users
             let check1 = i.Services.Any(p => p.UsersSelectMeetingCriteria.Any(k => k.ID == CurrentUserID))
             let check2 = i.GeographicalAreas.Any(p=>p.UsersSelectMeetingCriteria.Any(o=>o.ID == CurrentUserID))
             let check3 = i.MultiplyItems.Any(r => (r.UsersSelectMeetingCriteria.Any(q => q.ID == CurrentUserID) && r.ItemType == MultiplyItemKeys.USER_TYPE))
             let check4 = i.MultiplyItems.Any(s => (s.UsersSelectMeetingCriteria.Any(q => q.ID == CurrentUserID) && s.ItemType == MultiplyItemKeys.COMPANY_INVOLVED))
             let level = 5 - (check1 ? 1 : 0) - (check2 ? 1 : 0) - (check3 ? 1 : 0) - (check4 ? 1 : 0)
             where i.ID != CurrentUserID && level <= 4
             select new {i, level};
```

What this does is performs your checks independently then subtracts the number of succeeded checks from 5. Thus if three succeed and one fails, you will have 5-3 = "level 2".

Note, if I am actually on the right track here, this looks like a giant mess and an even bigger hack. I'd be inclined move the logic to a stored procedure or try to simplify it somewhere else in the data model.

Note 2, I've also dutifully ignored your commented code.

Note 3, I'm sure there is a better way to do this if I were to know your data model and reasoning behind the query.